# Concurrent User lockout with Spring Security

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot

I thought I had this issue resolved with this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34401172/spring-security-locks-user-out-with-concurrent-login-attempts).  However, I found a new use case that is causing issues, so please pardon the duplication.  I have a Spring-boot application that uses Spring-Security 4.0.2.  I do not allow concurrent logins, and can confirm that you cannot login twice in separate browsers.  I see that the browser apparently shares the session as I can login from two different tabs of the same browser (Chrome, Safari, Firefox, IE11 tested).

What I am seeing is that when I attempt a third browser tab login, the authentication fails. That is the expected and desired behavior, but what is not acceptable is that the user account is locked out and a server restart is required.  I examine the database records and that user account still has everything enabled.

I set breakpoints and stepped thru `org.springframework.security.core.sessionSessionRegistryImpl`  and
`org.springframework.security.web.authenticationSimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler` and I cannot see anywhere that the user is being blocked.  I have my debug levels:

```
logging.level.org.springframework:INFO
logging.level.org.springframework.web: INFO
logging.level.org.springframework.security:INFO
logging.level.org.springframework.security.web.authentication:INFO
```

and I cannot see any exceptions or error messages being thrown.  here is my primary config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private SessionRegistry sessionRegistry;

    @Autowired
    ServletContext servletContext;

    @Autowired
    private CustomLogoutHandler logoutHandler;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
                    throws Exception {
        auth
                        .userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService)
                        .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                        .addFilterAfter(new CSRFTokenGeneratorFilter(), CsrfFilter.class)
                        .authorizeRequests()
                        .antMatchers("/", ).permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated()

                        .and()

                        .formLogin()
                        .loginPage("/loginPage")
                        .permitAll()
                        .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                        .defaultSuccessUrl("/?tab=success").failureUrl("/")
                        .and()
                        .logout().addLogoutHandler(logoutHandler).logoutRequestMatcher( new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                        .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                        .invalidateHttpSession(true).permitAll().and().csrf()

                        .and()  // Instructs Spring Security to use the Servlet 3.1 changeSessionId method for protecting against session fixation attacks,
                                        // also we set maximum session to 1
                        .sessionManagement().sessionAuthenticationStrategy(
                        concurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy()).sessionFixation().changeSessionId().maximumSessions(1)
                        .maxSessionsPreventsLogin( true).expiredUrl("/login?expired" ).sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry )
                        .and()
                        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)
                        .invalidSessionUrl("/")
                        .and().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();

        // Here we protect site from:
        // 1. X-Content-Type-Options
        http.headers().contentTypeOptions();
        // 2. Web Browser XSS Protection
        http.headers().xssProtection();

        http.headers().cacheControl();
        http.headers().httpStrictTransportSecurity();
        // 3. X-Frame-Options
        http.headers().frameOptions();

        // Inject servlet context and set http only (for increased security you should always customize http only to true)
        servletContext.getSessionCookieConfig().setHttpOnly(true);
    }

    // CORS protection
    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping( "/**" ).allowedOrigins( "*" )
                                .allowedHeaders( "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*" )
                                .allowedHeaders( "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with" )
                                .allowedMethods( "GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE" )
                                .maxAge( 3600 );
            }
        };
    }


    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        // default strength = 10
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public static ServletListenerRegistrationBean httpSessionEventPublisher() {
        return new ServletListenerRegistrationBean(new HttpSessionEventPublisher());
    }


    @Bean
    public ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy concurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy() {

        ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy strategy = new ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy(sessionRegistry());
        strategy.setExceptionIfMaximumExceeded(true);
        strategy.setMessageSource(messageSource);

        return strategy;
    }
}
```

I also have a LogoutHandler to handle extra sessions (I think this is what Quchie was referring to?):

```
@Component
public class CustomLogoutHandler implements LogoutHandler {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger( CustomLogoutHandler.class );

    @Autowired
    private AuditService auditService;

    @Autowired
    private SessionRegistry sessionRegistry;

    @Override
    public void logout(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse,
                       Authentication authentication) {

        if (authentication != null && authentication.getDetails() != null) {
            try {

                User user = (User)authentication.getPrincipal();

                auditService.logoutUser(user.getOffice());
                httpServletRequest.getSession().invalidate();


                httpServletResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
                //redirect to login
                httpServletResponse.sendRedirect(Urls.ROOT);

                List<SessionInformation> userSessions =  sessionRegistry.getAllSessions(user, true);

                for (SessionInformation session: userSessions) {
                  sessionRegistry.removeSessionInformation(session.getSessionId());

                }

                List<Object> principals = sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals();

                if (principals.contains(user)) {
                    throw new Exception("User not removed from session!");
                }
                LOGGER.debug( "user logged out" );

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                e = null;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Can anyone help me find out how to prevent the user account from being locked on a failed concurrent login attempt?  Or at least make it have a time so it unlocks have a certain time amount?

Edit:
I cannot understand why it locks out for extended periods of time (days) if it was just storing in session.  The database records are never set to a bad state, but yet the user account is locked out until I restart Tomcat.

Comment: SessionRegistryImpl stores session for logged in user. You basically need to clear it off once the user is logged out. If you don't, no user can logged in with the same id. My recommendation is to implement a custom LogoutHandler that remove session in SessionRegistry. I have similar explaination here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35185118/2048098

Comment: Thank you Quchie, I updated my question with a LogoutController. I looked at the example you linked to but could not find a springSecurityService anywhere. Is that a Groovy only implementation?